# angular1 to angular2 directive-function with compile

Tags: angularjs, angular, ng-upgrade

What can be done to upgrade NG-1 to NG-2 where the directive has "compile" in it.
Eventhough in doc they say "compile. This will not be supported in Angular 2", can anybody suggest me if any cheats available?..

Comment: Angular2 directive doesn't have template metadata.

Answer (score 1):

Directive in **Angular2** doesn't have **template metadata**. So you can't think of compiling directive's template as it is not available.

**Angular2** directive's have different ways to implement the things. Everything depends upon your use case how  & what exactly you want.

Comment: How can we achieve the compile in Angular2...!, my use-case is something which has to generate Widgets/Layouts from model-data.

Comment: I understand compile is there in angular1 for directive's template. But it is not same in angular2. Though you can check with [ngUpgrade](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/upgrade.html) if something is there then.

Comment: ya, since Angular2 doesn't support compile, ng-upgrade not possible, it's mentioned in the same doc under : "Using Component Directives"..

Comment: Yes that what I said. come up with code so somebody can help you.